# product flavors producing incorrect build variants

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

```
flavorDimensions 'publish', 'develop'

productFlavors {
    live {
        dimension 'publish'
    }

    dev {
        dimension 'develop'
        applicationIdSuffix ".dev"
    }
}

buildTypes {
    debug {
        minifyEnabled false
        shrinkResources false
        zipAlignEnabled true
        debuggable true

        productFlavors.live.signingConfig buildSignConfig.debug
        productFlavors.dev.signingConfig buildSignConfig.debug
    }

    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        zipAlignEnabled true
        debuggable false

        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

        productFlavors.live.signingConfig buildSignConfig.release
        productFlavors.dev.signingConfig buildSignConfig.release
    }
}
```

I have 2 library modules and in application gradle file, I have above flavorDomensions, productFlavors and buildTypes. This produces build variant incorrectly like liveDevDedug and liveDevRelease. What could be the possible errors? Using AS 3.0

Comment: Assuming what you're looking for is `liveDebug`, `devDebug`, etc then you only need single `flavorDimensions` value

Comment: got it now.. a big thanks